# Объединение строк

Tags: c#

Привет. 2 день знаком с C#. Пытался, как в Java, объединить строки, чтобы выполнить запрос:

```
"https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?oid="+uid+"&need_user=0&count=0&offset=0&access_token="+access_token"
```

Но строки не объединяются. В чём ошибка?

**Обновление**

```
public class Authorization {
    String login;
    String password;

    String accessToken;
    String uid;

    public Authorization(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String StartAuthorize() {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Authorize);
        browser.Navigate("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4846118&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&scope=audio&display=wap&response_type=token");
        return "success";
    }

    public void Authorize(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        HtmlDocument document = ((WebBrowser) sender).Document;
        HtmlElementCollection inputs = document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].GetAttribute("name").Equals("email")) {
                inputs[i].SetAttribute("value", login);
            }
            if (inputs[i].GetAttribute("name").Equals("pass")) {
                inputs[i].SetAttribute("value", password);
            }
            if (inputs[i].GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit")) {
                inputs[i].InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }

        if (!((WebBrowser) sender).Url.ToString().Contains("access_token")) {
            inputs = document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit")) {
                    inputs[i].InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
        accessToken = document.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split('&')[0];
        uid = document.Url.ToString().Substring(document.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf('=')+1);
    }
}
```

С помощью такого кода получаю access_token через VK api. В этих строчках:

```
 accessToken = document.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split('&')[0];
        uid = document.Url.ToString().Substring(document.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf('=')+1);
```

Успешно присваиваются данные к строкам (проверил с помощью отладки), но в этой строчке:

```
return "success";
```

Переменные null. Я так понял, что return происходит раньше, чем WebBrowser успеет выполнить свою часть кода. Как исправить это?

**Обновление 2**

Как сделать, чтобы WebBrowser дождался загрузки страницы и в то же время остальная часть кода подождала, когда WebBrowser выполнит все поставленные ему задачи.

Comment: что такое uid и access_token вы предлагаете угадать?

Comment: @DreamChild я думал очевидно, что это переменные типа String

Comment: Для вас это очевидно - вы с этим кодом работаете. Другие этот код видят впервые, и, разумеется, понятия не имеют, что вы решили объединять в одну строку. А вообще было бы неплохо, если бы вы дали больше информации о коде и ошибке

Comment: Нечего там больше добавлять :) Создаю таким образом строку, а во второй строчке ее вывожу. Но выводится без этих переменных.

Comment: А чему равны сами эти переменные? Выведите их тоже.

Comment: Если использовать простые строки:

    String first = "first";
            String second = "second";
            Console.WriteLine("begin" + first + "mid" + second);

То все нормально, если же использовать в строке "URL":
http://s017.radikal.ru/i438/1501/56/fff4f176f5cc.png
то строки не обьединяются

Comment: @thejadefalcon: Напишите минимальный кусок кода, который показывает проблему. У меня, например, всё работает: http://ideone.com/dsbCdh

Comment: @DreamChild Вы были правы насчет проверить переменные, проверил, оказывается проблема посерьезней. Обновил в вопросе

Comment: @thejadefalcon ну вообще-то вы свой **Authorize** используете как коллбэк. Когда он отработает - неизвестно, потому и переменные при выходе из метода еще не установлены

Comment: >Как сделать, чтобы WebBrowser дождался загрузки страницы и в то же время остальная часть кода подождала, когда WebBrowser выполнит все поставленные ему задачи

если без  говнокода и костылей, то никак - юзайте **async/await**

Comment: @thejadefalcon: Покурите вот этот код:

    static class WebBrowserExtensions
    {
        static Task CompleteNavigate(this WebBrowser self, string uri)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler h = null;
            h = (o, args) =>
                {
                    self.DocumentCompleted -= h;
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                };
            self.DocumentCompleted += h;
            self.Navigate(uri);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

Comment: Добавлю к ответу @VladD небольшое пояснение: http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/csharp-sync-to-async